# How to Update document data in firebase with react-native Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 37)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]The error I'm facing is "**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 37)**"

```
class AgentDashBoard extends React.Component{
  state={
    Couriers: [],
    ids:[],
    Courier_Location: "",
    Courier_Status: ""
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.subscriber=
      firestore()
      .collection("Couriers")
      .onSnapshot(docs =>{
        let Couriers=[]
        let ids=[]
        docs.forEach(doc=>{
          Couriers.push(doc.data())
          ids.push(doc.id)
        })
        this.setState({Couriers})
        this.setState({ids})
    })
  }
  updateshipment= (trackid)=> {
       firestore()
      .collection("Couriers")
      .doc(this.state.ids[trackid])
      .update({CurrentLocation: this.state.Courier_Location, CurrentStatus: this.state.Courier_Status})
  }

  
  render(){
    return(
      <ScrollView style={{...}}>
        <Text style={{...}}> Couriers for Delivery </Text>
          {this.state.Couriers.map((Courier, index) => 
            <View 
            key={index} 
            style={{...}}
                    >
                     <View style={{...}}>
                            <TextInput 
                                style={{...}}
                                onChangeText={text=>this.setState({ Courier_Location: text})} 
                                placeholder="Current Location">
                                    {Courier.CurrentLocation}
                            </TextInput>
                            <TextInput 
                                style={{...}}
                                onChangeText={text=>this.setState({Courier_Status: text})} 
                                placeholder="Current Status">
                                    {Courier.CurrentStatus}
                            </TextInput>
                            <Icon 
                                name="check" 
                                size={25} 
                                style={{...}} 
                                onPress= {(index)=>
                                    this.updateshipment(index)
                                } 
                                />

                        </View>
            </View> )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
export default AgentDashBoard
```

Is there a way to display the `CurrentLocation` and `CurrentStatus` in 2 textinputs as I have tried to do and then edit that location and status just for one instance within the same onPress function.
The `ids[index]` returns the document id correctly but I'm unable to use that what can I do?[image]

Comment: Can you please screenshot of any error that you are getting ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have added the screenshot